# jQuery Editable DataTable get value from Struts Action

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, struts2, datatable

I am using jQuery editable datatable to show and edit data (in cell editing). On server side I am using  Struts 2. On server side I am checking few conditions before updating cell value. If some conditions fails then I have to put corresponding message in response object and on client side take action according to message value or show proper message to user.

My jsp page code :

```
      .makeEditable({
            sUpdateURL: "editEntry",
            "aoColumns": [
                        null,
                        null,
                        {
                            indicator: 'Saving...',
                            tooltip: 'Click to edit '+$("#editLabel").val()+' name',
                            type: 'textarea',
                            submit:'Save changes',
                            fnOnCellUpdated: function(sStatus, sValue, settings){
                                alert("Entry Updated");                                 
                            },
                        }
                    ],


        });
```

My Struts Action Class:

```
public class EditMinistryAction extends ActionSupport{


    private String value;
    private String message;


    @Override
    public String execute(){

        //few conditions checking

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }


    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

I have checked response object through browser plugins, It is having my desired messages, but my problem is where to write the code to parse response object? Which function of editable datatable I have to override?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. If you've parsed response than you can read its value. What is the problem?

Comment: @AleksandrM I am able to read response object through browser plugin. My problem is where to write the code in jsp page to read that response.

Comment: Look if [this helps](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/display-error-messages-returned-from-server)